# can anyone help my to deisgn custom expandable list in flutter like my xd

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build design using custom ExpansionTile in a flutter with a custom design. But I can not make it like my xd design, because my complex design is so difficultto do with flutter. can anyone help me to do this design?
my xd design image

[this is my design I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otdn1.jpg)

Comment: Hi Ahmad. You might be able to get more help here if you improve your post along the lines explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
Widget expansion(BuildContext context, int i, {Color color}) {
    return custom.ExpansionTile(
        headerBackgroundColor:
            myCardOpenColor[i] == null ? colores[i] : myCardOpenColor[i],
        topBorderRadius: 16,
        bottomBorderRadius: ListCategories.length != 0
            ? i == ListCategories.length - 1 ? 16.0 : 0
            : 16.0,
        title: Container(
          height: 220.h,
          child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(width: 50.w),
                Image.network(ListIcon[i], color: myIconOpenColor[i]),
                SizedBox(width: 60.w),
                Text(
                  ListCategories[i],
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: cardTextStyle[i],
                ),
              ]),
        ),

//     leading: SvgPicture.asset(ListIcon[i]),
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 500.h,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: ListSubCategories.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 140.h,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HOME_SCREEN);
                        print("asas $i" + "- $index");
                      },
                      child: FittedBox(
                        child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(width: 80.w),
                              Text(
                                ListSubCategories[index],
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: publicStylegrayMedium,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.9),
                              Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                              SizedBox(width: 60.w),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: white,
        initiallyExpanded: false,
        onExpansionChanged: ((newState) {
          setState(() {
            for (int x = 0; x < myCardOpenColor.length; x++) {
              if (x == i) {
                if (flag != 1) {
                  flag = 1;
                  myCardOpenColor[i] = white;
                  myIconOpenColor[i] = primaryColor;
                  cardTextStyle[i] = publicStyleblueeMedium;
                } else {
                  myCardOpenColor[i] = null;
                  cardTextStyle[i] = publicStylewhiteMedium;
                  myIconOpenColor[i] = white;
                  flag = 0;
                }
              } else {
                myCardOpenColor[x] = null;
              }
            }
          });
//          if (newState)
        }));
  }
```